# group by rolling sum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on this particular problem and have tried really all sorts of different methods but can't seem to solve it.    I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    Sequence GameID PlayerA PlayerB Left_Right
   0    1     101    334    326      Right
   1    2     101    334    326      Right
   2    3     101    334    326      Left
   3    4     101    326    334      Left
   4    5     101    326    334      Right
   5    6     101    326    334      Left
   6    7     101    326    334      Right
   7    8     101    326    334      Right
   8    9     101    326    334      Left
   9    10    101    334    326      Left
```

What I essentially am going to ultimately created is two columns, one with a rolling sum number of 'Right' and another column of a rolling sum of number of 'Left'.  It is to be grouped by GameID and also PlayerA.  In the dataframe above I only show part of one gameid, as it is a snippit.  This is similar to a countif in excel where my if condition would be 'Right'.

My understanding in pandas is to use a pd.rolling_sum() function but i'm not quite sure how to groupby and apply it while setting a condition.  I've also tried using cumcount() to no avail

```
df.groupby(['GameID','PlayerA']).Left_Right.cumcount()
```

Ultimately one of the new columns would look like this.  I'm not sure where I would specify 'Right' in the function above.  When I did a pd.rolling_sum I used a shift, but again I couldn't find where to groupby with this.

```
pd.rolling_sum((df["Left_Right"] == "Right"), 10000000, min_periods=0).shift(1)


    Sequence GameID PlayerA PlayerB Left_Right  CountIf_Right
   0    1     101    334    326      Right          0  
   1    2     101    334    326      Right          1
   2    3     101    334    326      Left           2
   3    4     101    326    334      Left           0
   4    5     101    326    334      Right          0
   5    6     101    326    334      Left           1
   6    7     101    326    334      Right          1
   7    8     101    326    334      Right          2
   8    9     101    326    334      Left           3
   9    10    101    334    326      Left           2
```

So to go through that column, it is grouped by gameID and PlayerA and is a rolling sum / countif with the condition being 'Right'.   So in row 1, 0 rights have occured in rows above it.  In row 2, 1 has occured above it for the player in the game.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ultimately one of your column would look like what?

Comment: the countif_right one that was added on to the df.  sorry!

Comment: Why is it showing `2` for the first `Left` ? and why is the second last `Left` `3` ?

Comment: first left:  for player_A (334), in this game, there has been 2 total Rights thusfar.  second to last Left.  For player_A (326) in this game there has been 3 rights thusfar

Comment: But I thought for `Left`s you are only considering how many previous `lefts` have occured?

Comment: the countif_right column is only concerned on if it is 'right' .. thats the problem i'm having

Comment: So then for `left` why is it putting `2` ?

Comment: it isn't 'for left' .   the problem i have is i want to include a condition that only takes into account 'right' and disregards left